# Mysql union query duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a dating site and thanks to the great answers I managed to make this query. I am totally a newb:)

**The problem with this union query is that it does not seem to remove duplicate entries and I have no idea why**.

**username** - is the name of people who join the site;

**willingness** - is about what they are willing to do, part of their profile page.

For example, if I search for the word **"lunch"** (like in the query bellow), the query finds people that have the chars **"lunch"** in their **username** or in their **willingness** profile.

But sometimes, someone has both the word **"lunch"** in his **username** and in it's willingness profile.

How can i remove these duplicate rows?

I use this query for a php navigation code.

Can you please help?

```
result = mysql_query("

(SELECT 1 as sort_col,username,pic0 FROM ".$table." WHERE username IS NOT NULL AND username LIKE '%lunch%') 

UNION 

(SELECT 2 as sort_col,username,pic0 FROM ".$table." WHERE username IS NOT NULL AND age BETWEEN '28' AND '45' AND willingness LIKE '%lunch%' )

ORDER BY sort_col 

LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$rowsperpage."");
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround. You could use:

```
SELECT username, pic0 
FROM ".$table." 
WHERE ( username LIKE '%lunch%' ) 
   OR ( username IS NOT NULL 
      AND age BETWEEN 28 AND 45 
      AND willingness LIKE '%lunch%' 
      )
ORDER BY ( username LIKE '%lunch%' ) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sort_col` guarantees that the rows between the two queries will always be distinct (1 vs. 2), so no duplicates will occur.

Comment: This is strage, I am seeing them when I actually use the code, any idea why? keep in mind that the term "lunch" and the duplicate rows appear when the username is lets say "lunchy" and also that name as "lunch" in his profile. So the query lists them twice.

Comment: @webmasters As I said, the row where username is "lunchy" gets a sort_col value of 1 and the row where profile contains "lunch" gets a sort_col value of 2. Hence the two rows are not exact duplicates and are not deduped by the UNION operation.

Comment: Ty very much for clearing it up. Is there a way that for the username "lunchy" to delete it's profile row from the query, or something like that? Basicly find a solution to work around this?