# UNION generate duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-by, sql-order-by, union

I know that By default `UNION` does'nt generate duplicate rows. But in this case as I used the column `sort_col` for sorting purpose and that way `UNION` generate duplicate rows(actually not duplicate as `sort_col` is distinct in each `select`). To clarifie see this answer and the [**comments**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8582591/2826057) also
How to overcome this?

```
$key_word_1 = $what;    
$key_word_2 = $what."%";    
$key_word_3 = "%".$what."%";


(SELECT 1 AS sort_col, 
        chair.id_user, 
        chair.company, 
        chair.district, 
        chair.summary, 
        chair.place, 
        products.name 
 FROM   chair 
        LEFT JOIN products 
               ON chair.id_user = products.id_user 
 WHERE  ( chair.district LIKE ? 
          AND chair.place LIKE ? ) 
        AND ( chair.company LIKE ? 
               OR chair.summary LIKE ? 
               OR products.name LIKE ? 
               OR products.description LIKE ? ) 
 GROUP  BY chair.id_user) 
UNION 
(SELECT 2, 
        chair.id_user, 
        chair.company, 
        chair.district, 
        chair.summary, 
        chair.place, 
        products.name 
 FROM   chair 
        LEFT JOIN products 
               ON chair.id_user = products.id_user 
 WHERE  ( chair.district LIKE ? 
          AND chair.place LIKE ? ) 
        AND ( chair.company LIKE ? 
               OR chair.summary LIKE ? 
               OR products.name LIKE ? 
               OR products.description LIKE ? ) 
 GROUP  BY chair.id_user) 
UNION 
(SELECT 3, 
        chair.id_user, 
        chair.company, 
        chair.district, 
        chair.summary, 
        chair.place, 
        products.name 
 FROM   chair 
        LEFT JOIN products 
               ON chair.id_user = products.id_user 
 WHERE  ( chair.district LIKE ? 
          AND chair.place LIKE ? ) 
        AND ( chair.company LIKE ? 
               OR chair.summary LIKE ? 
               OR products.name LIKE ? 
               OR products.description LIKE ? ) 
 GROUP  BY chair.id_user) 
ORDER  BY sort_col 
LIMIT 
?, ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove sort_col, because actually union will join with order (second select result will be append to first select result and the third select result will be after second select result)

Comment: By default union always append the second result after first result. But if you want, you can order the after union run like: (select * from A) union (select * from B) order by XXX

Answer (score 0):

That's not duplicate rows. It's different rows cause of your sort column. You can make query over these ones grouping by all columns besides sort column. Like this:

```
SELECT MIN(sort_col) as sort, id_user, company, district, summary, place, name
FROM
(your query here)
GROUP BY id_user, company, district, summary, place, name
ORDER BY MIN(sort_col)
```